# Spring boot 3 controller returning jaxb classes without namespace

Tags: xml, spring, spring-boot, jaxb

I have a spring boot 3 project, a dependency to com.sun.xml.bind::jaxb-impl::5.0.0,
a class like

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Exhibitor", namespace = "http://xyz/exhibitorProfile")
public class ExhibitorType implements Serializable
{
...
}
```

and the following controller code:

```
RestController
public class TutorialController {
     @GetMapping(value = "/test", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
//    public JAXBElement<ExhibitonsType> getFairs(@PathVariable("lang") String language) {
    public ResponseEntity<ExhibitorType> getObject() {
        try {
            var exhibitor = new ExhibitorType();
            exhibitor.setHomepage("www.homepage");
            IDType id = new IDType();
            id.setValue("0815");
            exhibitor.setID(id);

            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(ExhibitorType.class);
            Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
            m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);

            // Write to System.out
            m.marshal(exhibitor, System.out);

            return new ResponseEntity<>(exhibitor, HttpStatus.OK);

        } catch (IdNotFoundException | IllegalLanguageException e) {
            throw e;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //return new ResponseEntity<>(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatusCode.valueOf(500), e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Wenn I browse my .../test url I see in Browser:

```
<ns4:Exhibitor homepage="www.homepage">
<ns1:ID>0815</ns1:ID>
</ns4:Exhibitor>
```

and in console:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns4:Exhibitor xmlns:ns1="http://xyz/find/common" xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ns3="http://xyz/query/exhibitionList" xmlns:ns4="http://xyz/query/exhibitorProfile" xmlns:ns5="http://xyz/exhibitorProgramDetails" homepage="www.homepage">
    <ns1:ID>0815</ns1:ID>
</ns4:Exhibitor>
```

How do I enable the namespaces to be output in controller response?

I googled and chatted, tried various library version of jaxb-impl with no success.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the XML-presentation in Firefox.
The complete XML in network console contains the namespaces.
It shows also correct in Chrome

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).